# get_post_meta($post->ID) returns empty string when in preview mode of custom post type

Tags: post-meta, previews

I've got my custom post type 'event'. I got tne next code in single-event.php:

```
get_header();
the_post();
echo '<pre>';
echo "$post->ID\n";
var_dump(get_post_meta($post->ID));
echo '</pre>';
```

When I open my event page by normal URI /event/slug/, I got this:

```
22681
array(17) {
  ["_edit_lock"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "1439329938:36"
  }
  ["_edit_last"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "36"
  }
...
}
```

When I open it for preview, like /event/slug/?preview=true&preview_id=22681&preview_nonce=XXXXXXXXXXXXX , I got only this:

```
22681
string(0) ""
```

(where first line is a correct post ID and is the same as preview_id param)

What am I doing wrong? And why `string(0)`, and not `array(0)`?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta#Hidden_Custom_Fields

Comment: Hi, @mayeenul-islam! Thank you for your reply, but it is not what I meant. What I have is `get_post_meta` returns essentially nothing - no underscored fields and no regular fields when called from preview.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with 3 lines of code after calling get_post_meta():

```
if (!is_array($post_meta)) { 
    $post_meta = array();
}
```

Comment: `$post_meta = (array) $post_meta;` would do what you need.

Comment: Hi, тёзка :) Thank you for you answer. Alas, you solved another problem. My problem was that of `get_post_meta` returns different values in preview and normal modes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question why it returns an empty string is listed in the comment of the `get_post_meta()` entry in the WP Developers docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/#comment-825

The function requires the following:
`get_post_meta( $postID, 'meta_key', $single=false );`

As the comment of the link above explains:
If a meta field with the given `$key` isn’t found for the given `$post_id`, the return value varies:

If `$single` is `true`, an empty string is returned.
If `$single` is `false`, an empty array is returned.

`$single` defaults to `false` and no `meta_key` has been given, therefore an empty array is returned.